# YouTube API Quota Blowing Up

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

So, I am totally stumped. I cannot figure out why I'm blowing the YouTube API quota. According to my records, I'm only making ~1000 get requests per day. But when it comes to the YouTube quota, I'm hitting the 20k limit.

However, when I look at the actual methods, I've only recorded 709 get requests on Playlist items (scanning youtube playlists for new reviews every ~20min) and 249 search reqeusts (searching YouTube for new game trailers).

I'm using the nodejs api / package.

I just refreshed the API key last week and deleted all unused API keys. I am very confident there's not a rogue API key out there.

Code samples...

```
const yt = google.youtube({version: 'v3', auth: 'XXXXXXXXX-my-api-key-XXXXXXXXX'});

function searchByVideoTitle (title, order, token, channelId) {
    let req = {
        part:'snippet',
        q: title,
        maxResults: 10,
        order: order || "relevance",
        pageToken: token || null
    };
    if (channelId) {
        req.channelId = channelId;
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        loggly.log('info', 'BlackWidow searching by video title: ' + title);
        fileLog.info('BlackWidow searching by video title: ' + title);
        yt.search.list(req, function (err, response) {
            if (err) reject(err);
 ...
        });
    });
}

function getPlaylistVideos (channelId) {
    currentPlaylistRequests++;
    if (currentPlaylistRequests > playlistLimit) {
        return Promise.reject(' too many requests ' + channelId);
    }
loggly.log('info', 'BlackWidow searching playlist: ' + channelId);
        fileLog.info('BlackWidow searching playlist: ' + channelId);
    return yt.playlistItems.list({part: "snippet", playlistId: channelId, maxResults: 10}).then(results => {
        
        return results.data.items.map(item => {
            return {
                title: item.snippet.title,
                description: item.snippet.description,
                publishedDate: item.snippet.publishedAt,
                externalUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.snippet.resourceId.videoId
            }
        })
    })
}
```

[image: Loggly logs]

[image: Quota page]

[image: Actual usage.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official docs, any given [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint call has a quota cost of 100 units; respectively, any given [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint call has a quota cost of 1 unit.

Thus, by way of elementary arithmetic: 249 search calls *times* 100 units *plus* 709 playlist items calls *times* 1 unit *equals* 25609 quota units.